# iOS notes app - drawing tools disappear when using Pencil

Tags: ios, ipad, notes.app, apple-pencil

I noticed the following behaviour and consider it a bug. How to proceed?

> When I open a new note in the iOS notes app (ipad pro 2020) and I open
> the drawing tools [1] and I start to draw with the Pencil then the
> drawing tools stay open (as expected).
>
> When I close the drawing tools [2] and reopen them [1] and I continue drawing with the Pencil then the drawing tools minimise as if the "Auto-minimise" option was active (but it is
> not).

This prevents e.g. the usage of the ruler tool (it disapears with the drawing tools).

Any idea how to appproach this? Can I file a bug report to Apple? Worth it?

[1] by tapping on the pencil icon in the lower right corner
[2] by tapping on "done" in the upper left

iPad Pro 11" 2020
Pencil 2
iOS 13.5 (17F75)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update to iOS 13.5.1 seemed to fix the issue. I got the hint in the Apple Discussion forums https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251558519?answerId=253012468022&page=1